# nginx proxy_pass to keep location for apps

Tags: docker, nginx

I would like to use nginx server as proxy for many web apps with Docker images.
So far, I was able to redirect requests to apps according to specific path.
The following code shows content of `default.conf` file.

```
upstream app1 {
  server app1:80;
}

upstream app2 {
  server app2:80;
}

server {
  listen       8080;
  server_name  localhost;

  location /app1/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://app1/;
  }

  location /app2/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://app2/;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

When I load the web page of one of this apps, the links do not have the app path in the URL.
For example, it shows `http://localhost:8080/somelink` instead of `http://localhost:8080/app1/somelink`.
The browser's address bar shows the correct URL (`http://localhost:8080/app1/`).
When I click in the link, the web browser follows the wrong URL.
Is there any solution to instruct nginx server to keep app path in the URL?

### Edit: reproducible example with Wordpress

The following code shows how to reproduce this behavior using Wordpress Docker image. The problem seems the same, when I access `http://localhost:8080/wordpress1` it redirects to `http://localhost:8080/wp-admin/install.php` instead of `http://localhost:8080/wordpress1/wp-admin/install.php`.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - wordpress1
      - wordpress2

  db1:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db1_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress1:
    depends_on:
      - db1
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db1:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress

  db2:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db2_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress2:
    depends_on:
      - db2
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db2:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress

volumes:
  db1_data: {}
  db2_data: {}
```

`default.conf`:

```
upstream wordpress1 {
  server wordpress1:80;
}

upstream wordpress2 {
  server wordpress2:80;
}

server {
  listen       8080;
  server_name  localhost;

  location /wordpress1/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://wordpress1/;
  }

  location /wordpress2/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://wordpress2/;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is not nginx issue. App1 and App2 must generate links with context (`/app1` and `/app2`). It is impossible force nginx to analyze backend response and change urls.

Comment: This is an in the HTML page which might be returning the the urls as `/somelink` and then browser will use `http://site/somelink`. So you need to fix your web app to return a base folder based on the request

Comment: @TarunLalwani I checked the source of the web page and the links do not have `/` at the beginning of the URL. For example `<A href="somelink">Text</A>`. I had the problem with the TCP port, after I added it to the header `Host` the browser showed the port. This is why I expected to keep the path of the app via nginx without changing the web app.

Comment: I checked and this would only happen if there is no trailing slash at the end of the URL.

Comment: @BukharovSergey any idea how to add context in URLs for apps based on `php:apache` Docker image?

Comment: The simplest way to integrate your app and nginx is use [nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy). it can automatically route request to backend. But it can works only with subdomains. I think wordpress also will work with subdomain much better then with context.